# PHP Update doesn't Update

Tags: php

The query runs in mysql, there is no catch when you submit but the data doesn't update. Is there any advice on why this doesn't work or even how to debug this?

```
<?php
if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST" )  
{
    // var_dump($_POST["first_name"]);
    try
    {

        // this needs to be a lot more secure! 
        // read PDO manual
        $id = $_GET['id'];

        // $description     = $_POST["description"];
        $first_name = $_POST["first_name"];
        $last_name  = $_POST["last_name"];
        $description = $_POST["description"];

        $sql = $db->prepare("UPDATE `exhibitors` SET first_name = '$first_name' WHERE id = '52'");


        $update = $db->query($sql);
    }
    catch ( Exception $e )
    {
        echo " Data could not be updated from the database.";
    }
}
```

and the connection:

```
<?php
    try
    {
        $db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=openstudios;port=8889","root","root");
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $db->exec("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
        // var_dump($db);
    }
    catch ( Exception $e )
    {
        echo "Could not connect to the database.";
        exit;
    }
```

Comment: You are not using `prepare()` correctly.

Comment: do echo ("UPDATE `exhibitors` SET first_name = '$first_name' WHERE id = '52'"` see what is the output

Comment: Are you using MySQLi or PDO?

Comment: Where are you declaring `$db`?

Comment: @Fred -ii-, I added that because of your first un-constructive comment "debug your code", Its obvious I'm just starting learning PHP.

Comment: @rocket Hazmat, I have it in a include:- Ill add it in my question above for reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not using `prepare()` (or `query()`) correctly here.  `prepare()` is used to create a "prepared statement" that gets ran with `execute()` and `query()` is used to run an SQL query string.

***DO NOT*** concatenate your `$_POST` values into your query string, that's how you open yourself up to SQL injections.  You are ignoring the *whole point* of using prepared statements.

This is for MySQLi:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];

// $description = $_POST["description"];
$first_name = $_POST["first_name"];
$last_name  = $_POST["last_name"];
$description = $_POST["description"];

$sql = $db->prepare("UPDATE `exhibitors` SET first_name = ? WHERE id = ?");
$sql->bind_param('sd', $first_name, $id);

$sql->execute();
```

See the docs: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

If you are using PDO, the syntax is a bit different

```
$id = $_GET['id'];

// $description = $_POST["description"];
$first_name = $_POST["first_name"];
$last_name  = $_POST["last_name"];
$description = $_POST["description"];

$sql = $db->prepare("UPDATE `exhibitors` SET first_name = :first_name WHERE id = :id");

$sql->execute(array(
    'first_name' => $first_name,
    'id' => $id
));
```

Comment: Actually Im not - I followed the team tree house tutorial that uses the PDO stuff - Im very new to PHP I would appreciate only constructive comments. You could of asked if I used mysql_ to connect and maybe explained why its bad, maybe linked to the best practice?

Answer (score 2):

For prepared statements you should be using something like this

```
$sql = $db->prepare('UPDATE exhibitors SET first_name = :first_name WHERE id = :id');
$sql->execute(array('first_name' => $first_name,'id' => 52));
```

In case you want to use query statement only, (which one should not, receptive to SQL injections)

```
$db->query("UPDATE exhibitors SET first_name = '$first_name' WHERE id = 52");
```